# MSBuild 15.0: warning MSB3245: Could not re solve this reference. Expected a file but got directory "\bin"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to migrate a Visual Studio 2015 solution to VS 2017 (15.4.1). Although the projects compile from within Visual Studio, if I try building the individual projects from the command line with MSBuild v15, compilation fails for any project that references a different project in the solution.

MSBuild outputs the following warning, which I think indicates that the referenced project can't be found:

> c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1988,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Expected a file but got directory "D:\TestSolution\ClassLibrary2\bin". If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\TestSolution\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj]

I start MSBuild using the following command:

```
"c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
    "d:\TestSolution\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj"
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. In Visual Studio 2017, create a new solution with two class libraries, `ClassLibrary1` and `ClassLibrary2`.
2. Let `ClassLibrary2` reference `ClassLibrary1`, and make sure code links to `Class1` of `ClassLibrary1`. Add the reference by right clicking on the 'Dependencies' node of the project in the Solution Explorer and select "Add Reference..." from the context menu.
3. Compile the projects from Visual Studio to verify that it compiles from Visual Studio.
4. Kick off MSBuild from the command line using the previous command. Building fails with the stated warning.

Besides the warning, there is the following error message:

> Class1.cs(7,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d
>   :\TestSolution\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj]

Project file for ClassLibrary1:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Project file for ClassLibrary2:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Class1 in ClassLibrary2:

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private readonly ClassLibrary1.Class1 instance = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();

        public string Test() => instance.ToString();
    }
}
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hey Steven, I have just tried locally and it worked well. Do you have latest VS 2017 and MSBuild installed?

Comment: How did you add the reference, use the solution to express dependencies between the projects or add the references to the project? If you add reference in solution (Right click your solution->Properties->Common Properties->Project Dependencies), then you build the project individual, you will get that error. BTW, try to clean the build, then re-build.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT: I added the reference by right clicking on the 'Dependencies' node of the project in the Solution Explorer and select "Add Reference..." from the context menu. Cleaning the solution made no difference. The error still remains.

Comment: @Steven, Can not reproduce. How about add namespace `using ClassLibrary1;` in the Class1 in ClassLibrary2?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT: It's certainly _not_ a code problem. MSBuild kicks of the same compiler. I did however manage to fix this problem in the test project by: 1. removing the /bin and /obj folders from the projects, 2. opening the solution in VS (that probably did a package restore, and recreated bin and obj folders), 3. close the solution, 4. run the MSBuild command. This fixed the problem in the test project, but unfortunately _not_ in the real project. I even tried `dotnet restore`, but the problem remains in the real project. Problem now is that I can't reproduce that exact problem in a test project

Comment: @Leo-MSFT: Again, note the core problem were, which is "Could not resolve this reference.". MSBuild is unable to find the project reference (or some unclear reason).

Comment: @Leo-MSFT: Do note that when calling `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe`, MSBuild does not supply the depending project as a `/reference` in my real project. In the test project however, it supplies `/reference:d:\TestSolution\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ClassLibrary1.dll` which causes that build to succeed.